# I have an issue with my loops to show the result value

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach

```
 $array_of_time = array ();
 $start_time    = strtotime ("$app_date 07:00");
 $end_time      = strtotime ("$app_date 22:00");
 $mins  = 04 * 60;

while ($start_time <= $end_time)
{
   $array_of_time[] = date ('h:i a', $start_time);
   $start_time += $mins;
}

echo "<div style='width:700px' class='time_slot_div'>";
echo "<p class='time_slot_p'> Time Slot :</p>";

foreach($array_of_time as $key=>$value)
{

    for($i = 0; $i < count($app_data); $i++)
    {
        $book_time=$app_data[$i]["appointment_time"];
        if($value==$book_time)
        {
           echo "<a  class='time_slot_a_book'>$value</a>&nbsp;";    
        } else {
           echo "<a href='#' onclick='get_time_value(\"$value\");' class='time_slot_a'>$value</a>&nbsp;";
        }
    }
}

echo "</div>";
```

Here foreach loop can run as many time as it can as well as for loop also, but i want to show the links that are not matched with the foreach value and for loop value.

The foreach loop values like 7:20 am not from database but the for loop value like 7:20 am is from database so if 7:20 am==7:20 am then the if statement it run it is working fine, but the issue is that it is running 2 time if i get 2 value in for loop. It should run my div only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If took a tour of your site, I revise the copy:

```
$array_of_time = array ();
$start_time    = strtotime ("$app_date 07:00");
$end_time      = strtotime ("$app_date 22:00");
$mins  = 04 * 60;

while ($start_time <= $end_time)
{
   $array_of_time[] = date ('h:i a', $start_time);
   $start_time += $mins;
}

echo "<div style='width:700px' class='time_slot_div'>";
echo "<p class='time_slot_p'> Time Slot :</p>";

foreach($array_of_time as $key=>$value)
{
  //
  // get the appointing state:
  //
  $bAppointed = false;
  for($i = 0; $i < count($app_data); $i++)
  {
    $book_time = $app_data[$i]["appointment_time"];
    $bAppointed = $value == $book_time;
    if($bAppointed)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  //
  // print the time slot:
  //
  if($bAppointed)
  {
     echo "<a  class='time_slot_a_book'>$value</a>&nbsp;";    
  } else {
     echo "<a href='#' onclick='get_time_value(\"$value\");' class='time_slot_a'>$value</a>&nbsp;";
  }
}

echo "</div>";
```

?

Is it better ?

Comment: Could you please explain more what did you want ? Do you want to break also in foreach($array_of_time as $key=>$value) ? By example as soon as possible.

Comment: foreach loop is showing time from 7:00 am to 10:00 pm with time slot gap of 4 minutes eg. 7:00 am 7:04 am 7:08 am and so on....
the second loop that is for loop is getting value for data base of saved time slot that is suppose in database is have saved value 7:04 am 7:08 am in two separate row then it will get the value by using query the after for loop will check how many time slot are save in our case it is two i.e  7:04 am 7:08 am then it will matches with the foreach loop value if matched it will go in if statement other wise in else statement

Comment: It's better if you explain more in your question. Give a list of example time and exactly what you want to show as time...

Comment: please go here http://www.webmakerindia.com/doctor/add_appointment.php
login as username:ajit password:123 then  after login go to appointment and select/click on add appointment after form will come please select doctor name and date then the data will come below the save button the time are repeating.i do't want to repeat the time

Comment: thanx jacouh i got the solution for this :D